# XSD/XML : cast data to Enum item or XmlEnumAttribute item

Tags: c#, xml, enums, xsd

I am stuck on a problem that I can not solve. So I appeal to you:

I have generated a class from an XSD via xsd.exe.
The XSD contains lists transformed into enumerations of this type:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.6.1087.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public enum BlocsListe
{
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("2 blocs")]
    Item2blocs,
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("4 blocs")]
    Item4blocs,
    /// <remarks/>
    ND,
}
```

The property that uses this enumeration:

```
    private BlocsListe _typeBlocs;
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public BlocsListe TypeBlocs
        {
            get
            {
                return this._typeBlocs;
            }
            set
            {
                this._typeBlocs = value;
            }
        }
```

I extract elements from my database through a DataReader and then try to assign the value contained in the database to the TypeBlocks property of my object.

And that's where I'm stuck.
In the database, the contents of the XmlEnumAttribute are stored.
I therefore have cases where I do not have values in database, other where I have a value corresponding to an item of the enumeration and cases where the value stored in the database does not correspond to No item in the enumeration.

I try to parse the contents of my DataReader to find the correspondance with one of the XmlEnumAttribute and then assign my property.
And I block on that.

To simplify things, some other enumerations do not contain an XmlEnumAttribute (see the "ND" of the enumeration above).

If you have any advice, I am a taker.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the following solution :

```
public static Dictionary<string,T> CheckEnumValue<T>(string value)
    {
        Dictionary<string,T> DicEnum = new Dictionary<string, T>();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            Type type = typeof(T);
            MemberInfo[] memberInfo;

            foreach (T b in Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)))
            {
                memberInfo = type.GetMember(b.ToString());
                object[] attributes = memberInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute), false);

                if (attributes.Length == 1)
                {
                    XmlEnumAttribute attribute = attributes[0] as System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute;
                    if (attribute != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(attribute.Name) && attribute.Name.Equals(value))
                        DicEnum.Add(attribute.Name, b);                            
                }
                else
                {
                    if (b.ToString().Equals(value))
                        DicEnum.Add(b.ToString(), b);
                }
            }
            return DicEnum;
        }
        return null;
    }
```